# Sending messages to people or channel who are not added already using slack api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, slack-api

I am working on a feature of my application where i have to send them messages when there is something to notify the user about, i have implemented sign in with slack to get the user data, i got the token, id of the user etc, now i want to either create a channel and invite that user, or send a message directly to them, but i am unable to do that, i have given all the scopes to Slack App, i have tried `conversations.invite`, `chat.postmessage` api but always get error , user_not_found, i am using react on the frontend and using package `react-slack-login` to signin the user

I have my app tokens and also user token, but unable to get the answer for my solution

```
<SlackLogin
   redirectUrl={"Redirect_URL"}
   onFailure={onFailed}
   onSuccess={onSuccess}
   slackClientId="Client_Id"
   slackUserScope="openid profile email"
/>
```